# wrapfigure within an exam

Tags: wrapfigure, exam

I am trying to float a figure using `wrapfigure` within an `exam` document using `minipage`. If I don't use a `minipage`, then the exam questions do not wrap around the figure. When I use `minipage` as in the example below, everything wraps, but if the `minipage` (or the longer form with solutions included with `\printanswers`) is longer than one page, then the typesetting runs off the bottom.

My simple question is this: what's the correct way to include figures in an `exam`? My example `questions` block follows:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{9cm}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./20x20grid-axes.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

\question Answer all parts below: 

\begin{parts}

\part[1] 1 + 1 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 2 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\part[1] 2 + 2 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 4 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\part[1] 3 + 3 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 6 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\end{parts}
\end{minipage}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Did I get the class and packages right? Otherwise please edit your question into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5):

One possibility would be to move the `minipage` inside the `parts` environment, and ending it as soon as enough material has been wrapped, as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Answer all parts below: 

\begin{parts}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{9cm}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./20x20grid-axes.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\part[1] 1 + 1 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 2 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\part[1] 2 + 2 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 4 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\part[1] 3 + 3 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 4 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}
\end{minipage}

\part[1] 3 + 6 = \answerline

\fullwidth{\begin{solution}\begin{align*} \boxed{ 6 } \end{align*}\end{solution}}

\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.